# Are there any issues with this FTL drive concept?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, physics, engineering, faster-than-light

I asked a question earlier on here concerning Negative and Heavy Matter - hypothetical types of matter I created to have a working FTL drive. With some extra work, I’ve tweaked the concept and been able to make an FTL drive I feel is pretty self-consistent. I’m asking this because I want to know if it is, or if there are any glaring flaws in its system of operation.

**How the engine works**

In the centre of the drive is a column of gas. This gas is an element that, when strongly heated, emits radiation that can convert ordinary matter into negative matter. This gas belongs to a class of matter called Heavy Matter, which strongly attracts Negative Matter - when Heavy and Negative Matter meet, they cancel each other out and convert back into normal matter. (I’ve worked all of these processes out on the subatomic level too but none of that is relevant to the workings of the engine.) The gas is heated to the point that it becomes a plasma, meaning a) it emits huge amounts of this radiation b) it can be confined by a magnetic field. Surrounding the confined column of gas is a vacuum - surrounding the vacuum is a much larger cloud of gas; it doesn’t really matter what element this is, let’s say it’s hydrogen for sake of argument.

The radiation hurtles outwards, converting the gas into negative matter. To maintain the vacuum gap between the negative and heavy matter (because otherwise the negative gas would drift inwards and convert back into ordinary matter as it hit the heavy matter in the centre) the whole drive is spun very rapidly, causing the cloud of gas to stick to the interior wall due to centrifrugal force.

**The FTL itself**

Once enough negative matter builds up, spacetime is warped, causing the entire ship to travel faster than the speed of light. The negative matter will be drawn to whichever heavy matter is exerting the most force on it - because very massive heavy matter at long distances exerts more force than fairly light heavy matter at short distances, instead of warping to the centre of the engine, it warps the entire ship over to a large concentration of heavy matter, deliberately placed as a beacon. Large concentrations of heavy matter nullify the effect of the warping, thus causing the ship to drop out of FTL once it reaches this beacon. This allows the ship to travel at superluminal speeds between regularly spaced beacons in the universe.

Once the ship is stopped at the beacon, the plasma is drained, the spinning stopped, and the entire chamber flooded with water. Normal matter reacts with negative matter to form radiation - the result being that the accumulated negative matter is destroyed along with some of the water, readying the ship along with the next jump.

Attached is a cutaway view of this drive.

What do you guys think? Allowing for the mechanisms of Heavy and Negative matter, how feasible is this? Are there any issues or interesting effects I haven’t anticipated? [image]

Comment: You might want to reformat this post in a few ways; split up that wall of text for easier consumption, and rotate the image to display horizontally so folks don't have to crane their necks to look at it.

Comment: I edited your Post see if this is better you can revert or change it yourself if you don't like it.

Comment: Good question ! - You might want to address the issues surrounding mass changes as the ship approaches C... (unless this is already done...)

Comment: Relativistic effects don’t actually enter into this, Joe. This is based on a real life concept of FTL travel called the Alcubierre Drive - the way it works means that the ship can traverse distances in a shorter period of time than light can (so it technically exceeds c) by compressing space behind the ship and expanding it in front of the ship, while actually travelling at a fairly low velocity.

Comment: This is not similar to any description of the Alcubierre Drive I have ever heard. It sounds essentially like saying you can reach light speed if you have a really strong magnet at your destination and if your ship is made out of "negative matter". Whatever that is and how it relates to regular matter is unclear. It's also unclear how the ship is supposed to survive ramming head first into the "magnet" at the destination at superluminal speeds. Or how it fully converts back to regular matter.

Comment: By the way, there is also an argument that even if we managed to build an Alcubierre Drive that it still would not achieve FTL. You see, the drive must warp spacetime in order for the ship to pass through it, however the information of that warp cannot travel faster than light, so the best you can hope for is a little less than light speed. Now, if you warp the spacetime from the source to the destination ahead of time, THEN you can travel faster than light. But I believe these are called Krasnikov tubes.

Comment: @Muuski: One of the more outlandish theories bounced around between the astrophysics students when I was at uni was that the evidence for dark matter/energy was really observations of the side effects of some elder civilisation building lanes of warped space between far-flung colonies. They never got the maths to work out, but I enjoyed the idea!

Comment: How does the ship leave the beacon? Currently it is pulled by the large mass of the beacon, but once there no other beacon can pull the ship (otherwise it would have left course for that particular beacon). So you would be stuck there. Perhaps you could do something with turning the beacon on/off, or being able to shield the effects like a lighthouse shields the light from particular area's.

Comment: I kinda glossed over this point in my explanation for sake of wordcount, but I did consider it. The positive warping effect of the Alcubierre Drive has to be the same magnitude as the negative warping effect of the beacon for them to cancel. So if the pilot wants to pass a particular beacon - power up the engine, so the drive warp is too big for the beacon to cancel it, even if it does slow down. If they want to stop at a particular beacon, power down the engine, so the drive warp is small enough to be cancelled. Does that make sense?

Comment: Would you mind specifying the process by which normal matter is converted to your negative matter? That seems to be probably the most handwaviest (/most impossible?) bit in here, and it would be good to understand it a bit more.

Comment: One big problem: "Normal matter reacts with negative matter to form radiation".  This means your centrifugal chamber will turn the whole ship into one big burst of gamma rays.

Comment: I recommend swapping the [tag:science-fiction] tag with the [tag:reality-check] tag.  You're asking a reality-check question and the sci-fi and sci-bas tags don't usually go together.

Comment: Almost everything in this question is irrelevant noise, i.e. details that don't really affect the question itself.   It could all be reduced to "_Are there any issues with this FTL drive concept?  ... spacetime is warped, causing the entire ship to travel faster than the speed of light._".  The entire question describes in detail _how_ spacetime is warped, but provides no information about _why_ warping spacetime would cause the ship to travel faster than light.

Comment: The space between the ship and its destination compresses, and the space behind the ship expands, depositing it at its location and allowing it to get there before light can, without ever actually exceeding c.

Comment: @Locaq The biggest issue with this FTL drive is that it violates causality and you can easyly create time travel paradoxes with it, as you can with any kind of FTL drive. Read this for further information www.physicsmatt.com/blog/2016/8/25/why-ftl-implies-time-travel .

Comment: I think the design of that internal chamber is going to run into trouble with Boyle. It's a hollow tube that intends to create a "donut" vacuum via centrifuge. A vacuum is really hard to achieve and I'm really skeptical you can create one this way -- especially with gases that desperately want to expand to fill that volume. And even if you could, this would prevent having a central non-vacuum column of gas. I'd just handwave the whole thing via plasma & magnetic containment.

Comment: That’s a good point

Comment: Based on what I’ve read here, I’ve refined my drive concept. Here’s the new concept: a disc-shaped ship with a ring of Salirium running around the edge. Surrounding this is a ring of tungsten. When the ship is ready to go, the Salirium is heated until it becomes a plasma, and held in place on the edge of the ship by a magnetic field. The radiation emitted by the Salirium converts the tungsten to negative matter. Salirium is attracted to another, different type of heavy matter I’ve called Argosum. The attraction of the ship to the nearest Argosum beacon pulls the ship there (continued)

Comment: (continued) where the effects of the Argosum collapse the warp bubble, and then convert the negative matter formed so far back into normal matter. Sound good?

Answer (score 11):

Yeah? I mean: you’ve kinda created some handwavium at the point you say ‘spacetime is warped’ with no further explanation of the physics or mechanism behind it, at which point you may as well simply say ‘Our drive uses negative matter to warp space between it and the nearest heavy matter beacon’, and simply don’t mention the internal workings of the drive (unless it becomes a plot point).

One immediate issue is that your forces are working backwards. Beacons further away exerting more attractive force will lead to ships stranded in interstellar space, unable to move towards any beacon because of the attractive powers of the other beacons. Unless you can add some form of directional selection to your ‘space warping’ you’re basically going to get stuck where you are. If you’re more attracted to close, heavy beacons then you are distant ones then you just end up stuck at whatever beacon you’re at, unable ever again to taste sweet freedom. If you can ‘shield’ your drive from the effects of beacons in any given direction, or if multiple warp vectors start to form and you can choose which to set off along then you can avoid this issue.

If you fix that another issue is all of the stuff between your ship and your target beacon. It’s about to get torn apart by a spontaneously forming corridor of warped space, or possibly hit by the leading edge of a bubble of warped space. Alcubierre based warp metrics don’t take your ship out of normal space: it’s still here, just wrapped in a bubble of *immense* tidal stresses. A major flaw with the Alcubierre-White warp metric (Alcubierre being the guy who came up with it, White being the guy currently working on it) is that particles (both of interstellar dust and virtual particles from the quantum foam) get stuck on the bubble. Depending on how you run the numbers this either means the inside of the bubble becomes incandescently hot or your destination is about to be bathed in a rather major wave of high energy radiation. Both of these are Bad For All Involved, so you should consider dedicated space lanes with rigorous traffic control procedures.

There are other issues. One is time travel, more specifically the fact that you can’t have special relativity, FTL and causality in the same place because [simultaneous events aren’t](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-trouble-with-ftl-588cb3a3a03c). You can potentially get around that with a liberal application of general relativity, but then you risk messing with gravity or time (or both) in unexpected ways. Another issue I assumed to be handwaved by your new exotic matter is spontaneously blowing up your ship by annihilating large amounts of matter, as mass is proportional to energy (Thanks, Einstein), and you can’t get around conservation laws, so the first and final steps of your drive function (conversion of regular matter to an exotic state, then annihilation of said matter) result in needing then releasing frankly ludicrous amounts of energy.  But hey, it’s a writer’s prerogative to ignore these issues, as long as it makes the story better.

So yeah, utterly non scientific and has issues, but as totally handwavy soft science FTL drives go i’ve heard worse justifications.

Comment: The warp part isn’t handwaved. It’s based on the Alcubierre Drive - look it up. General Relativity predicts that an accumulation of negative mass (technically, negative energy density) will lead to the creation of a warp bubble that travels FTL without interacting with anything in its path.

Comment: Could you go into more detail about the other issues you mentioned?

Comment: I think I kinda failed to convey my point about the beacons. Force doesn’t increase with distance. Force increases with mass at a greater rate than it decreases with distance. A very massive beacon at say, 10 light years away exerts more force than a very light beacon a metre away, and also more force than a very massive beacon 12 light years away, for example.

Comment: @Locaq: You have handwaved. Regardless of what you’ve based it on, the interaction you’ve created is a handwave. You’ve invented an exotic state of matter then stated it acts (in some way which is actually very unlike the physics of an alcubierre drive) to warp spacetime like an alcubierre drive. That’s a handwave. It’s a perfectly fine one, but there’s no way we can critique it as it is fundamentally your creation.

Comment: @Locaq: I spent a lot of my uni days and more time than I should have afterwards digging into the physics of the Alcubierre-White warp metric and it’s attending engineering problems. Alcubierre drives definitely do interact with things in their path: in fact one of the major flaws in the alcubierre drive is superheated plasma on the hypothetical ‘front’ of the bubble.

Comment: @Locaq: If mass is also taken into account then every ship will end up stuck to the heaviest beacon. Same issue: you need some form of directionality to allow you to ‘aim’ your warped space, a simple distance/mass equation turns into a minimum-energy-state optimisation and your ships will end up in some local minima, unable to get out.

Comment: @Locaq More details added. :-)

Comment: @JoeBloggs I think your answer hits a point that is very important (the handwave part). It is something that is often overlooked.

Comment: Lemme explain my reasoning here. Firstly, I’m aware of the particle buildup. What I meant is it wouldn’t interact with like, macroscopic objects. The paths would be drawn to avoid passing through bodies anyway (because if the drive was disengaged at that point it’d be pretty disastrous for the body), but if it passed through say, a planet, it wouldn’t damage it in the process unless it stopped. Yeah, I’ll acknowledge that’s a handwave.

Comment: Lemme explain my reasoning about the beacons. The imaginary equation I devised was F = M^8/d where F is the attractive force, M^8 is the mass, and d is the distance. So on a given ‘FTL railway line’ of beacons, you’d have like 10 beacons of a ton mass each, separated by a light year of distance. Starting at the first beacon, the forces experienced by the NM to the HM inside the ship, the second beacon, and the tenth beacon respectively are 0.008N,                1.1 x 10^8N, and 1.1 x 10^7N. So it’ll be drawn to the second beacon, where it can either stop or keep going, and so on.

Comment: @Locaq you've missed something rather important there, I think.  Sure, you've fudged the formula so that the next beacon pulls harder than the HM inside the ship.  That's not particularly hard anyway.  However, once you get to that beacon, the force of from the next-next beacon is still weaker than the force from the beacon right next to you.  You will always be stuck at your current beacon.  Which is one of Joe's points.

Comment: I think I should probably give up on trying to make a scientifically consistent and detailed FTL drive and just handwave everything

Comment: @Locaq Yes, you should. If we had the science to do that, somebody would have gotten a Nobel price for discovering it and be more famous than Newton and Einstein combined. This has not happened so we just do not have the science for it and you will almost certainly fail. So not worth spending lots of effort beyond making the hand waves sound good. Unless of course your actual goal is to win the Nobel price and be more famous than Newton and Einstein combined, in that case it would actually be one of the better avenues to pursue.

Comment: @Locaq: Consistent and detailed are good, but unless it’s important to the plot for some reason it’s generally better to focus on the function of the drive rather than the mechanism. In your case you have a drive filled with negative matter that can selectively create Alcubierre style warp bubbles that are drawn towards beacons of heavy matter.

Comment: @Locaq: If I were you I’d say that when starting the drive it starts to warp space in multiple directions, and once your ship starts to go down one vector it becomes self-reinforcing and the other bubbles collapse behind the ship. That would be consistent with the theoretical framework behind Alcubierre drives (notably that the motion of the ship when the bubble forms is crucial as the bubble just acts like a velocity multiplier rather than a drive in itself). The exact mechanism behind why and how your drive does this is handwaved, but the function of the drive is detailed and consistent.

Comment: Yeah, I think being nonspecific is good. So basically once the ship starts to head in a given direction it will only warp in that direction?

Comment: @Locaq: That’s what I’d go with. Sort of a ‘snap to’ effect, where the drive starts to form warp bubbles/corridors to the nearest few beacons, and you give your ship an push to cause it to ‘fall’ in one direction or another. Of course: it’s your drive! As long as you pick a mode of operation and stick to it you should be fine.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any issues or interesting effects I haven’t anticipated?

The centrifugue must necessarily be located within the ship. And this means that, when the space around the gas distorts, the ship will be distorted as well.

This has the potential to break not only molecular bonds, but also the bonds between subatomic particles as well. Your version of Alcubierre might have just plasma arriving at the destination.

Also notice that it is debatable if even Alcubierre's drive can provide actual FTL travel. See Muuski's comments on the question.

Comment: I’m not entirely sure I understand could you clarify?

Comment: You are distorting the space between particles inside the ship. That does not bode well.

Comment: Ah, fair point.

Answer (score 1):

This is really basic question, not highfalutin' like the other questions here, but...

What is the diameter of the tube, and how fast does your tube have to spin, to create a vortex that has a vacuum in the center?

You have the cutoff between "NM gas" and "vacuum gap" be sharp, but I think it would be some kind of gradual fade, though I'm not sure if the density-curve of that fade would be linear.

I do not think, through rotation, that you can accomplish anything even close to a perfect vacuum, particularly given the energies (and hence, gas pressures) involved.

If you've already done the math, great, I won't bother.

If not, we probably need to calculate it, and I'm suspecting that you might need to pass light speed for your centrifuge walls in order to get the vacuum, and you'd end up compressing almost all of the gas down to a liquid.

Comment: Yeah I doubt it’d be a perfect vacuum. Considering the central part of the engine is far hotter than the outer parts, gas wouldn’t flow inwards that much anyway. It’d just need to rarify the gas between the plasma and the cloud enough that the negative matter wouldn’t be destroyed.

Comment: The heat is energy, which would excite the gas atoms, so, yes, the heat would cause it to flow inward a LOT. This feels like it will break your mechanism completely, and probably needs us to do the math. But that seems like a separate problem, worth a separate question :)

Comment: This was an interesting question in itself, so I asked it here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/480713/in-a-spinning-tube-how-low-can-the-vacuum-in-the-center-be